# Is it possible to reduce the amount of gas for transferring ether to multi accounts via smart contract?

Tags: solidity, gas

I want to transfer the same amount of ether to 100 different addresses.
I'd like to reduce the amount of gas for it.

I tried to do it with such contract:

```
contract MultiTransfer {

  function transferEther(uint amount, address[] users) public payable {
    require(amount * users.length == msg.value);
    for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      users[i].transfer(amount);
    }
  }

}
```

As result, it requires 3422830 gas for tx with 100 addresses. ~ 34K gas per 1 address.
But it costs only 21K if transfer ether directly without contracts.

So smart contracts can't help to reduce gas for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they can't help you. Smart contracts also create transaction for each address. And transaction cost is 21k gas.